# Reading 2 numbers of line of a file from end and putting them in arrays

Tags: c, arrays, file-io

I have an input file where I have 2 very long numbers (somewhere at 10^4 digits) separated by a space. What I have to do is to read them , both of them from last digit to first and put them in 2 separate arrays.
Here is an example for 2 short numbers:

1234 5678

My program needs the numbers like a[ ]={4,3,2,1} and n[ ]={8,7,6,5} to work. Is it possible, or do I have to read them and reorder the digits? Thank you for help!

Answer (score 0):

Well, you have at least 3 options to do that, one you already said.

The two other options would be:

- make a fseek() in every char read, what I do not recommend, since you will have a very slow program.
- use memory-mapped files, which is basically map an arbitrary file into a memory address, this way, you get exactly what you want but with a penalty of a platform-dependent solution, so, solutions for Windows, Linux... will become differents.

A POSIX compliant (Linux e.g) solution would be something like:

```
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define error(msg) \
{                  \
    perror(msg);   \
    exit(-1);      \
}

int main()
{
    int i;          /* Loop index.     */
    struct stat s;  /* stat structure. */
    int  fd;        /* File descriptor.*/
    char *file;     /* Mapped file.    */

    /* Open the file. */
    if ( (fd = open("file", O_RDONLY)) < 0 )
        error("Failed open file");

    /* File size. */
    if ( fstat(fd, &s) < 0 )
        error("Failed to stat file");

    /* Maps the file into memory. */
    if( (file = mmap(0, s.st_size, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, fd, 0)) == MAP_FAILED)
        perror("Failed to map file");

    /* Starts reading. */
    for (i = s.st_size; i >= 0; i--)
        printf("%c", file[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

if you want to do something like in Windows I recommend you to reading this: [Managing Memory-Mapped Files](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms810613.aspx).

For better understanding the code above, please refer to [open](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/open.html), [fstat](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fstat.html) and [mmap](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/mmap.html).